# Are state funerals always held on a Monday?

Tags: monarchy, royalty

Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth II will be laid to rest on Monday. I'm interested to know if state funerals are specifically held on a Monday, or this one just happens to be.

Searching around, I can find a lot of information about the day monarchs died, but not the date of the funeral, see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_funerals_in_the_United_Kingdom#State_funerals) for example.

Anyone able to help me find a list of funeral dates for UK monarchs? Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the individual Wikipedia entries for each monarch? George VI's funeral was 15th February 1952, which was a Friday. George V' funeral was 28th January 1936 which was a Tuesday, etc.

Comment: One wonders if Monday/Friday is not on purpose to allow for an extended weekend as many public holidays are.

Comment: @SteveBird I did, and very few of the individual's monarchs' pages state the date of the funeral. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to wikipedia, Winston Churchill had a state funeral which was held on [Saturday, January 30th 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_1965#January_30,_1965_(Saturday)), so the answer is "no", state funerals are not always held on a Monday.

Comment: Thanks. As it happens, after a lot of trawling through the individual monarch's pages on Wikipedia (see the link in my question), I discovered that Queen Anne was buried on a Tuesday, so even if we restrict it to monarchy, the answer is still no. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This may be relevant to the thinking behind the question.

It was planned well in advance that the funeral of Her late Majesty, our dearly beloved Queen, would be on the tenth day after her death, unless she died on a Thursday in which case it would be the 11th day after her death. As it happened she died on a Thursday so her funeral is Monday.

The reason for Thursday being 11 is to avoid having a funeral on a Sunday, the Christian holy day.

So there was no rule that it had to be a Monday. It could have been any day but Sunday.

Comment: Thanks for that, very interesting